# How i can fix legend ? (MPAndroidChart)

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I used `legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART_CENTER);` it works, but I want that the legend was at the top

if i use `legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART);` the legend and the graph overlap

maybe there is a way to change the position of the chart?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the desired result using

```
legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.ABOVE_CHART_LEFT); 
legend.setWordWrapEnabled(true); 
legend.setMaxSizePercent(0.20f);
```

Answer (score 2):

This method deprecated better to use this.

```
l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
l.setDrawInside(false);
```

for reference you can check here [The legend can't display when call setPosition(LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_CENTER)](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2281)

Answer (score 1):

Use below line:

```
   legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.ABOVE_CHART_RIGHT);
```

Comment: but then the names are placed in a row and not vertically

Answer (score 1):

try to Set all the data to chart after all customization and everything will work fine .. like this  :

```
 l.setCustom(arrayOf(firstLegend, secondLegend))
    l.verticalAlignment = Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM
    l.horizontalAlignment = Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT
    l.orientation = Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL
    l.setDrawInside(false)
```

and then set the data to chart  ..

```
        chart.data = data // set the data and list of labels into chart
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can when you changing the value of the offset:

```
    pieChart.setExtraTopOffset(15);
    pieChart.setExtraBottomOffset(15);
    pieChart.setExtraLeftOffset(0);
    pieChart.setExtraRightOffset(50);
```

Or with one line

```
    setExtraOffsets(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)
```

result:

[image]

A good example with its parameters and with some description:
https://www.programmersought.com/article/99524092993/