# Legend.setPosition() is not a valid method?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Using the newest version of the MPAndroidChart. Android Studio 3.6, sdk 29.

```
Legend legend = lineChart.getLegend();
legend.setPosition() // this is red, no such method. obviously would have a LegendPosition in it
```

Every other method for Legend works, just not setPosition. What am I doing wrong?

I found one user [saying it was deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147748/how-i-can-fix-legend-mpandroidchart) but he links to a thread from 2016, and .setPosition is in the wiki updated in Nov 2018, so I'm not sure if that's the case or not.

**Edit**: Using the method described by that user, I was able to get the same effect. Still curious about the state of .setPosition(), is it deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

**legend.setPosition is deprecated.**
*you should use below piece code*

```
 legend.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
 legend.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
 legend.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
 legend.setDrawInside(false);
```